# seabon catplot: change position on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am plotting two seaborn categorical plots (pointplot and swarmplot) on top of each other and just can't figure out how I can change the x axis position of one of them (i.e. the swarm plot in my particular case) so that instead of overlapping the plots are 'side by side' (i.e. ideally I want to have the individual data points to the right of the mean and ci).

Here's the code to produce the plot:

```py
import seaborn as sns

# set style and font size
sns.set(style='white', rc={'figure.figsize':(6,6)}, font_scale=1.3)

# plot means as points with confidence intervals
a = sns.pointplot(x='Group',
                  y='RT',
                  data=data,
                  estimator= np.mean,
                  capsize=.2,
                  join=False,
                  color='black',
                  size=12)

# plot individual data points as swarmplot
b = sns.swarmplot(x='Group',
                  y='RT',
                  data=data,
                  size=8,
                  alpha=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: You can just add some offset to the x-data of swarm plot. You didnt provide the data so people can't provide a final answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't provide the orginal data points and admit that I was too lazy to create a toy example just for asking this question. Sorry. However, the word 'offset' in your comment pointed me in the right direction. It's not easy to add an offset when the data is categorical but I found this post which helped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195997/how-to-add-axis-offset-in-matplotlib-plot

Comment: Should this be closed as duplicate or would you say the question is sufficiently different to deserve its own answer?

Comment: Hmm. It's borderline, I guess. I will update the question with the code needed for the solution.

Comment: Since no further answer appeared here, I closed as duplicate now. If you think that the answer(s) to the linked question do not fully adress the problem, you may provide an answer over there. This is in the interest of future readers finding all relevant answers in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the axis handle to the `sns`.

I am not sure whether this is what do you want!

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig,ax =plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,7))
sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips,
              ax= ax[1])

sns.pointplot(x='day',
              y='total_bill',
              data=tips,
              estimator= np.mean,
              capsize=.2,
              join=False,
              color='black',
              size=12,ax=ax[0])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am afraid that this is not what I meant. I guess my description wasn't very precise. I wanted to have the mean and individual points in the same axes but side by side for each xtick. I have found another issue that gets me there half way (see my comment above).