# Is there a way to stagger or dodge multiple matplotlib.plot error bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to view the std error bar for each dataset but they are overlapping each other. Is there a way to stagger the error bar for each dataset? 
Here is the code I am using:

```
group=hms.groupby([ hms.index.month]).mean()
std=hms.groupby([ hms.index.month]).std()
group.plot( linewidth=2,yerr=std)
[enter image description here][1]
```

[Line Graph with Error bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peRgx.png)

Comment: I think I answered that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195997/how-to-add-axis-offset-in-matplotlib-plot) already.

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn's [`pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) has that option baked in. Just set the parameter `dodge` to `True`.

You'll probably have to reformat your data into a "long" format though. Then create a new column with just the months to use as your x axis. I can't tell you exactly how without sample data.

```
sns.pointplot(x='month', y='value', hue='group', data=hms, ci='std', dodge=True)
```

Otherwise, you can just add shift your x values by some small amount for each group and use the standard matplotlib library.